# What T-SQL datatype could accumulate the result of adding these numbers together?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, numeric

My procedure generates the following series of values, one value with each iteration of a loop. What datatype could accumulate them?

```
71
4225
592704
4.97871e+007
1.16029e+009
3.51298e+011
4.90223e+012
4.06068e+014
2.07119e+016
1.74901e+019
8.75078e+019
1.64097e+022
3.69721e+023
8.27212e+025
1.56207e+027
6.14425e+030
6.59974e+030
4.33538e+034
2.78839e+034
3.05904e+038
1.1781e+038
1.49158e+040
3.79264e+042
3.23534e+043
1.27933e+048
1.36693e+047
9.02694e+051
7.58263e+053
3.75394e+052
3.44945e+055
1.58604e+056
2.7189e+058
1.82166e+060
4.35566e+061
```

Comment: What is the maximum value that you wish to store? The sum that you've shown fits comfortably within a float (albeit with limited precision), but the sum of the sequence, extended further, won't.

Comment: [`BIGINT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) won't handle the values, let alone an sum of them. [`FLOAT(53)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) may be your best option, though it lacks the precision to handle all of the values.

Comment: The maximum value would be POWER(84,50).

Comment: But then I'd like to take a modulo of the accumulated value. I'm trying to write a no-collision hashing function to return an integer offset when fed a varchar(50) and an integer TotalBuckets parameter, e.g. 10001.  offset = func( myVarchar,  10001).